# Custom font usage in wkwebview

Tags: javascript, css, swift, wkwebview

While trying to use custom Malayalam font in my app the wkwebview is not resulting in correct font format.
The same code works fine in uiwebview but in wkwebview the font is not recognised or the font is not correctly added.

code:

```
font-face { font-family: 'ML-TTKarthika'; src: url('ML-TTKarthika-Normal.ttf')}
```

Comment: @NightFury I have tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: found out the error. the font url was not described. hence the baseurl has been linked to NSURL.fileURL(withPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)) and the font had been recognised